# Can't implement Phase Listener in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to use phase Listener in one of my beans in jsf but it's not working.

**Class:**

```
package com.mycompany.creditcard1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.Flash;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "userDetailsLogin1")
@ViewScoped
public class UserDetailsLogin1 implements Serializable, PhaseListener {

    private UserDetails userDetails;
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("inti");
        userDetails = (UserDetails) flash.get("userDetails");
        if (userDetails == null) {
            userDetails = new UserDetails();
        }
    }

    public UserDetailsLogin1() {
    }

    public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public String action() {

        flash.put("userDetails", userDetails);
        return "UserDetailsLogin2?faces-redirect=true";

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
        System.out.println("after phase");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;

    }

}
```

**faces-config file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>com.mycompany.creditcard1.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
```

**Error:**

Unable to create a new instance of 'com.mycompany.creditcard1.MyPhaseListener': javax.faces.FacesException: com.mycompany.creditcard1.MyPhaseListener

Don't understand why it is showing this?
Any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well start by replacing `<phase-listener>com.mycompany.creditcard1.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>` by `<phase-listener>com.mycompany.creditcard1.UserDetailsLogin1</phase-listener>`... you have the wrong class name!

Also, I don't know if it is a good practice to mixup Bean and PhaseListener into the same class...